# How to merge two dataframes and then multiply result with a different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix-multiplication

I'm collecting Exchange rate data from one API source and international stock prices from another source, and want do denominate the returns to a single currency.

The problem is that the information about the symbols needs to be matched to the corresponding currency, and then multiplied with the exchange rate to get the denominated returns.

I simply can't wrap my head around how to combine these operations most efficiently.

How can I merge the symbol and exchange rate information, and how do I then multiply the result most efficiently with the stock prices?

Example data, limited to fewer currencies and symbols than actual

Pivoted fx data

```
                           Rate                                         Units
Currency    Danish krone  Euro  Swedish krona  US dollar Danish krone  Euro  Swedish krona  US dollar 
Date                                                     
2016-01-04  128,98        9,62     104,22      8,9578    Hundreds      Units    Hundreds     Units 
2016-01-05  130           9,69     104,52      8,923     Hundreds      Units    Hundreds     Units
```

Raw FX data, csv format

```
Exchange rates,Business,Swedish krona,Norwegian krone,Spot,2016-01-04,105.21,2,false,Hundreds,ECB concertation time 14:15 CET
Exchange rates,Business,Swedish krona,Norwegian krone,Spot,2016-01-05,103.95,2,false,Hundreds,ECB concertation time 14:15 CET
Exchange rates,Business,US dollar,Norwegian krone,Spot,2016-01-04,8.8525,4,false,Units,ECB concertation time 14:15 CET
Exchange rates,Business,US dollar,Norwegian krone,Spot,2016-01-05,8.9224,4,false,Units,ECB concertation time 14:15 CET
Exchange rates,Business,Euro,Norwegian krone,Spot,2016-01-04,9.6475,4,false,Units,ECB concertation time 14:15 CET
Exchange rates,Business,Euro,Norwegian krone,Spot,2016-01-05,9.588,4,false,Units,ECB concertation time 14:15 CET
Exchange rates,Business,Danish krone,Norwegian krone,Spot,2016-01-04,129.29,2,false,Hundreds,ECB concertation time 14:15 CET
Exchange rates,Business,Danish krone,Norwegian krone,Spot,2016-01-05,128.52,2,false,Hundreds,ECB concertation time 14:15 CET
```

It is also possible to get the data in a beta JSON or XML format.
https://www.norges-bank.no/en/Statistics/open-data/get-data/

Stock data

```
Symbols             AAPL    ASSA-B.ST   BMW.DE  CARL-B.CO
Date                
04.01.2016 00:00    105,37   175,8     94,71    618
05.01.2016 00:00    105,85   175,2     93,5     612
```

Mapping dataframe to link symbols to fx rate

```
Symbol      Currency
AAPL        US dollar
ASSA-B.ST   Swedish krona
BMW.DE      Euro
CARL-B.CO   Danish krone
```

The expected output, which i am unable to produce using python is

```
Symbols                AAPL     ASSA-B.ST    BMW.DE     CARL-B.CO
Date                
04.01.2016 00:00     943,88      183,22      911,35      797,10 
05.01.2016 00:00     944,50      183,12      906,72      795,60
```

The formula for currency conversion is price * currency for currencies in units,
and price * currency /100 for currencies in hundreds.

Comment: pivoted fx data. is that actually the format? it *looks* very messy when u posted it here on SO

Comment: Yes, doesn't seem to be easy to present tables in this forum. I have updated the presentation of the data it to make it more readable.

Comment: would you mind providing fx not pivoted. I guess it might be easier to take it from there

Comment: Updated with more details on the FX data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear with me, because there is some cleaning and tweaking to do to get the result needed;

*first off, please provide data easily to convert to input for others to use. Plain text, .csv and .xlsx are usually best.*

1. subset your dataframe and convert 'Rate' to units:

   ```
   df1 = df1.rename(columns = {2:'Currency', 5:'Date', 6:'Rate', 9:'UoM'})
   df1 = df1[['Currency', 'Date', 'Rate', 'UoM']]
   df1['Rate'] = np.where(df1.UoM == 'Hundreds', df1.Rate / 100, df1.Rate)

           Currency        Date    Rate       UoM
   0  Swedish krona  2016-01-04  1.0521  Hundreds
   1  Swedish krona  2016-01-05  1.0395  Hundreds
   2      US dollar  2016-01-04  8.8525     Units
   3      US dollar  2016-01-05  8.9224     Units
   4           Euro  2016-01-04  9.6475     Units
   5           Euro  2016-01-05  9.5880     Units
   6   Danish krone  2016-01-04  1.2929  Hundreds
   7   Danish krone  2016-01-05  1.2852  Hundreds
   ```
2. your 'stock-data' is df2 (I had to clean that part, the datetime format differs from the other data you provided, in addition to swapping ',' for '.' in the values);

   ```
   df2

                 AAPL  ASSA-B.ST  BMW.DE  CARL-B.CO
   Date                                            
   2016-01-04  105.37      175.8   94.71        618
   2016-01-05  105.85      175.2   93.50        612
   ```
3. your 'symbols'-frame is df3 here. add the symbols to df1 with merge and then groupby to get a dataframe similar to 'stock-data' (df2);

   ```
   merg = pd.merge(df1, df3, on='Currency')
   df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
   merg = merg.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol'])['Rate'].sum().unstack()

   merg

   Symbol        AAPL  ASSA-B.ST  BMW.DE  CARL-B.CO
   Date                                            
   2016-01-04  8.8525     1.0521  9.6475     1.2929
   2016-01-05  8.9224     1.0395  9.5880     1.2852
   ```
4. format both dataframes to numeric, multiply the dataframes and round to 2 decimals;

   ```
   cols = merg.columns
   merg[cols] = merg[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
   cols2 = df2.columns
   df2[cols2] = df2[cols2].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

   fin = merg.mul(df2)

   fin.round(2)

   Symbol        AAPL  ASSA-B.ST  BMW.DE  CARL-B.CO
   Date                                            
   2016-01-04  932.79     184.96  913.71     799.01
   2016-01-05  944.44     182.12  896.48     786.54
   ```

note; the values in the end differ from yours. that's because the data you provided later on is different.

Comment: Works great. However, new issue is then to add local currency (NOK) as 1 for local stocks. My intention was to insert a column of 1's in the pivoted fx dataframe, but unsure how to add row of 1 in the datarange. I need to add a range of rows of 1, corresponding to the dates all observations of dates from the fx dataframe. Local stocks now returns as 0, since the currency is missing.

Comment: You mean UoM? Try a nested np.where

Comment: Please post a follow up question and refer to this one. Probably not that easy to add in the new problem, but might be mistaken.